# discord.py wait_for check isnt working properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make something that asks the user a question and checks if the answer is correct. But when I come to check if the answer = the recorded answer it shows False, although I checked that they are equal.
So the bot does not congratulate the user for saying the correct answer, it just ignores the answer. This is what happens:
[image]

This is my code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.id == 1051856493764415568:
            if message.author.bot:
                return
            else:
                rand_num = randint(4,6)
                if rand_num == 5:
                    ss = open('scrambled sentences.txt','r')
                    sslist = ss.readlines()
                    chosen_sentence = choice(sslist)
                    cs_list = chosen_sentence.split("|")
                    question_msg = await message.reply(f"Unscramble the following sentence in 10 seconds for a chance to win a firework:\n\n{cs_list[0]}")

                    def check(m: discord.Message):
                        print(m.content)
                        print(cs_list[-1])
                        #When I tried printing these two they are identical
                        return m.channel.id == m.channel.id and m.content.lower == cs_list[-1]

                    try:
                        msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check = check, timeout = 10.0)
                    except asyncio.TimeoutError: 
                        await question_msg.reply(f"Noone sent the correct answer in the 10 seconds provided...")
                        return
                    else:
                        await msg.channel.send(f"**{msg.author}**, you responded with {msg.content}!")
                        return
                        #await message.channel.send(f"{msg.author.mention} was first! He gets one firework. The answer was:\n\n{cs_list[-1]}")
```

This is `scrambledsentences.txt`:

```
Question) `RsgaD si het btse reve!`|drags is the best ever!
Question) `RsgaD si het torws reve!`|drags is the worst ever!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are **not** equal. `str.lower` is a **function** & you're not calling it.

```py
... and m.content.lower == cs_list[-1]
```

This is always `False`, because a function will not be equal to a string, so your check always fails.

```py
>>> "TEST".lower == "test"
False
>>> "TEST".lower
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7f8110ec7ab0>
```

You can solve it by... well, *calling* the function.

```py
m.content.lower() == cs_list[-1]
```

You said you printed them and they were equal, yet you're printing `m.content` instead of `m.content.lower`. If you're trying to debug-print to check if two things are equal, you should print those very things to see that they aren't. Printing something *different* isn't useful so you might as well not print anything at all then.

```py
# Print the first, the second, and the boolean that comes out of it
# If that isn't True then they aren't equal
print(m.content.lower, cs_list[-1], m.content.lower == cs_list[-1])
```

This would instantly show you what you're doing wrong.